# Creating a dynamic form_tag inside an each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, loops, model

I have a model called assignment that has_many :questions models, which in turn belongs_to  assigntment. Questions have a string field called content. In the show.html.erb for my assignment I have a loop that iterates through each question and displays it.

```
<b>questions:</b>
  <% @i=1 %>
  <% @assignment.questions.each do |q| %>
      <p>question <%= @i %><p/> 
      <%= q.content %>
       <%=#need to generate text_area forms here %>
      <% @i= @i+1%>
      <br/>
  <% end%>
```

The user (a student model that has_many: answersheets models, which in turn belongs_to :student) needs to fill in the answers and then hit submit. The submit needs to create a new answersheet object (which has columns student_id assignment_id and answer_responses as a string). I need to grab all the answers as strings, concatenate them (with a divider in between such as a ";") and the answer_responses of the newly created answersheet model needs to be set to that string.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this question is a bit open-ended, but here goes...

First of all, you will probably only want one form to accomplish this goal. It can contain many fields, but it is best to keep everything you want together in a single form (otherwise you will need to resort to some javascript shenanigans to put the data together).

So now our view is starting to look like this:

```
<b>questions:</b>
<%= form_tag do %>
  <% @i=1 %>
    <% @assignment.questions.each do |q| %>
        <p>question <%= @i %><p/> 
        <%= q.content %>
         <%=#need to generate text_area fields here %>
        <% @i= @i+1%>
        <br/>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

But wait - `@i` has excessive scope, it could be simply `i`, and all of this incrementing `@i` doesn't seem very rubyish... We can switch it to use the [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method to clean this up a bit...

```
<%= form_for :answersheet do |f| %>
  <b>questions:</b>
  <% @assignment.questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
    <p>question <%= index %><p/> 
    <%= question.content %>
    <%=#need to generate text_area fields here %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Well, that's a little better, but now it's kinda obvious that the question inside of that loop could be easily abstracted out into its own partial (probably `_question.html.erb`):

```
<p>question <%= question_counter %><p/> 
<%= question.content %>
<%=#need to generate text_area fields here %>
<br/>
```

Leaving us with:

```
<%= form_for :answersheet do |f| %>
  <b>questions:</b>
  <%= render @assignment.questions %>
<% end %>
```

OK, great, but what about `<%=#need to generate text_area fields here %>`? Something like this in your partial should do the trick:

```
<p>question <%= question_counter %><p/> 
<%= question.content %>
<%= content_tag :textarea , '' , name: raw( "answers[#{ question_counter }]" ) %>
<br/>
```

This will allow you to do something like this in your controller:

```
Answersheet.create( answer_responses: params[:answers].values.join(';') ) if params[:answers]
```

Currently, this will post to the same controller/action as initially rendered the page. You may wish to add an additional route to send it to its own controller/action instead - you can supply that route as an argument to [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag). Also, this does not take into account the possibility that invalid data could be entered, which would need to be retained while displaying an error message to the user. Nor does it account for redirecting the user, or displaying a success message upon a successful submission. If you need more complexity, you may consider switching to [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) and using an actual instance of answersheet, with more properly restful routes. I deliberately did not use a form_for, in this example, as the data being sent is not directly usable by the model. You might consider making `answers` a method on answersheet that gets munged into `answer_responses` before save, or something, if pursuing that route (or maybe doing it with javascript, upon submission, which feels like a not great idea). Like I said, a bit open-ended. At any rate, this should be more than enough to get you pointed in the right direction - good luck!